# Load array from plist in Documents Directory

Tags: iphone, arrays, directory, documents

I use to load plist which are in my main Bundle (Ressource folder) into an array using :

```
 NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:nomPlist ];
 NSMutableArray *tmpQuestion = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
 arrayQuestion = [ [NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tmpQuestion]; 
 [tmpQuestion release];
```

since i decide to change the content of my plist and that main bundle is read only how can i make this array loading plist from the Documents directory of my app ? ?

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

`[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]]` will get you your app's Documents directory. On first launch, use `NSFileManager` to copy the plist file from your app's bundle to the documents directory. Afterwards, always open it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the file in app's documents directory exist

- YES : then use this file
- NO : this is the first launch, so copy it from the apps's bundle